# Upgrade old Virtual Box machine to latest Virtual Box standard

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have an old Windows XP machine created with Virtual Box prior to version 4 on a Mac OS (High Sierra).

The machine is working regularly, but it still has old .xml configuration rather than .vbox, even though I have upgraded Virtual Box regularly during all these years.
It also has the hard disk in a folder named 'hard disk' which is the old way VBox managed the .vdi.

I have red from the documentation that VBox doesn't upgrade old machines by default but instead it left them untouched for retro compatibility.

The machine is working fine (since ages) but I wonder if there's a simple way for upgrading it, such as cloning, exporting/importing, dealing manually with conf file....or things like that.

A quick tentative I have done, is to move the .vdi from the hard disk folder to the machine folder trough the Box console and it wen fine, then I have renamed the .xml to .vbox but this is not simply working, as VBox is telling me that another machine with same ID already exists. So I gave up and I am looking for a more structured way.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can export and then import a machine and it upgrades from .xml to .vbox. This might also work by just cloning it. Next, you can also clone the disk using [clonemedium](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/vboxmanage-clonemedium.html) and the —format setting. I hope this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: [if it ain't broke, don't fix it](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_it_ain%27t_broke,_don%27t_fix_it).

Comment: I ended up cloning the machine, with "total" as option. I will keep the old one as a backup and start working with the new machine.